# Python: compare a string to a reference string to see what percentage of the letters are the same

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and I'm trying to work with strings.

I have some data with peptides for example (test string) `KGSLADEE`. I want to write a function which compares the test string to the reference string: `AGSTQKP` to see what percentage of the letters in the test string are the same as in the reference string. How can I do this? When looking online I can only find code for exact string matches.

**For this example:**

```
(1*K) + (1*G) + (1*S) + (1*L) = 4 (letters which are the same)
```

Divide by 8 (total number of letters in the test string)

```
(4/8) * 100 = 50%
```

How can I do this? When looking online I can only find code for exact string matches.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also please provide an exact definition of what you want to achieve. `letters which are the same` - at the same position? In relation to the length of the string 1 or 2? ...

Comment: Also, a bit more definition - if you have duplicate letters, how do you handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you searching for something like this?

```
def f(test, ref):
    d = dict()
    for c in ref:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = min(ref.count(c), test.count(c))
    return sum(d.values()) / len(test) * 100

f('KGSLADEE', 'AGSTQKP') # 50%
f('hello', 'h') # 20%
f('abc', 'cba') # 100%
f('a', 'aaa') # 100%
f('aaa', 'a') # 33.333%
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is what I'm trying to do but I'm having trouble understanding what you've done. Specifically, what is c?

Comment: i'm looping through each character in the reference string, using your example with the reference string `'AGSTQKP'` the first cycle `c = 'A'`, the second cycle `c = 'G'`, etc... If you have a problem at understanding this type of code i can recommend you to study the official python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This yields the same results as the answer from Hoxha Alban, but I find this one a bit easier to read. It uses the Counter module (see here: https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html)

```
from collections import Counter

def f(test, ref):
  intersection = Counter(test) & Counter(ref)
  return len(list(intersection.elements())) / len(test) * 100
```

Comment: nice idea using the intertsection

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop through every letter in your test string. Your loop will go through each letter and check that letter within your reference string and then give you an output.

You can then use this output to calculate your percentage.

Answer (score 0):

```
word1 = 'KGSLADEE'
word2 = 'AGSTQKP'

same = 0

for letter1 in word1:
    for letter2 in word2:
        if letter1 == letter2:
            same += 1
            break

print(same/len(word1)*100)
```

It is not a solution for all situations. But you can expand that

Comment: if `word1 = 'aa'` and `word2 = 'aa'` the result is `200`

Comment: Hmm, as I said it is just an idea. But we can edit like that:

just adding "break" after same += 1